# Why jdbc statement doesn't make changes in mysql table

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
 statement.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM persons WHERE id=1");
 statement.executeUpdate("UPDATE persons SET first_name = 'first' WHERE 
 id=3");
 statement.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM persons WHERE first_name = 'Dmitrij';");
```

These statements don't make changes in table in DBeaver. Why not? Two first statements are executed in Idea, and make Delete and Set, but only in jdbc, not it Mysql. The third even not executed in Idea. Can anybody clear it to me?

```
public class MeetingService {

    private static Connection connection;
    private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/homeworks?user=root&password=123456";
    private List<Person> users;

    MeetingService() {
        this.users = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    static {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private Connection getConnection() {
        if (Objects.isNull(connection)) {
            try {
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return connection;
    }
```

and then i have a method:

```
void deleteFromUsers() throws SQLException {

        try(Statement statement = getConnection().createStatement()) {

            statement.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM persons WHERE id=1");
            statement.executeUpdate("UPDATE persons SET first_name = 'first' WHERE id=3");
            statement.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM persons WHERE first_name = 'Dmitrij';");
        }

    }
```

Comment: jdbc uses bydefault commit, show us some more code!

Comment: What does your data look like before and after?

Comment: You should get an exception (I guess SQLSyntaxErrorException ) for the 3rd statement because of the semicolon. This is forbidden to make SQL-Injections harder. 

And one more hint: `user=root&password=123456` is really a bad habit. Change this even on your local machine and even "just to test something".

Comment: my data is a table in DBeaver. It's just a list with person's data. And if i do any update or delete from jdbc, it doesn't make any changes in DBeaver table. It stay the same. But if i make SELECT query from jdbc i can see changes. I've deleted semicolon, but third statement can't be executed fully.  I'm learning jdbc so passwords and users don't matter now.

Comment: @ArifMustafa You're wrong, a JDBC connection is in auto-commit mode by default.

Comment: Make sure that DBeaver doesn't use transactions, or otherwise start a new transaction when trying to observe the changes.

Comment: how can i check it?

Comment: @ArifMustafa I didn't understand you either. 'Bydefault' isn't a word. You used it twice. Please don't make up your own terminology.

Comment: @EJP I simply used the *bydefault* as a word to understand, what's happened in jdbc automatically, there is nothing a terminology kind of thing.

Comment: @ArifMustafa You used a word that doesn't exist and nobody understood you. Why are you surprised?

Answer (score 0):

Remove semicolon(;) in

```
'Dmitrij';
```

try it like

```
statement.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM persons WHERE first_name = 'Dmitrij'");
```

Comment: i tried so but it was the same. The program can't finish executing.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't find any wrong in the below source code and have tested and running fine.

[image: Query Result]

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class MeetingService {

    private static Connection connection;
    private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/homeworks?user=root&password=password";

    static {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private Connection getConnection() {
        if (connection == null) {
            try {
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return connection;
    }

    void deleteFromUsers() throws SQLException {
        try(Statement statement = getConnection().createStatement()) {
            statement.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM persons WHERE id = 1");
            statement.executeUpdate("UPDATE persons SET first_name = 'first' WHERE id=3");
            statement.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM persons WHERE first_name = 'Dmitrij'");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        MeetingService service = new MeetingService();
        service.deleteFromUsers();
    }

}
```

both delete and single update is running fine and there is nothing to do with semicolon.

Comment: I've found out what was the problem.It was in my DBeaver. Before i call SELECT * FROM persons i have to click Commit. And then every changes in database shown correctly. Thanks.